# Using SQL Functions in eloquent select statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using `Laravel Framework 6.16.0`.

I want to select data via sql functions, such as `CONCAT('Q', QUARTER(transaction_date))`.

However, I get an error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CONCAT('Q', QUARTER(transaction_date))' in 'field list'
```

The query looks like the following:

```
$days = 365 * 2; // two years

$trx = DB::connection('mysql_prod')->table('product')->select(array("transaction_date", "CONCAT('Q', QUARTER(transaction_date))", "YEAR(transaction_date)", "trx_type", "amount_range", "transaction_value", "symbol"))
    ->leftJoin('companies', 'product.companies_id', '=', 'companies.id')
    ->leftJoin('persons', 'persons.id', '=', 'product.persons_id')
    ->where('companies.symbol', '=', $s->symbol)
    ->where('persons.person_type', '=', 'manager')
    ->whereDate('transaction_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays($days))
    ->orderBy('transaction_date', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Any suggestion how to use SQL-functions within an eloquent select statement?

Appreciate your reply!

Comment: you would need to use a `DB::raw` for the CONCAT stuff as it thinks you are trying to select 'columns' with `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lagbox stated in his comment,

You should change `"CONCAT('Q', QUARTER(transaction_date))"` to `DB::raw("CONCAT('Q', QUARTER(transaction_date))")`

```
$days = 365 * 2; // two years

$trx = DB::connection('mysql_prod')->table('product')->select(array("transaction_date", DB::raw("CONCAT('Q', QUARTER(transaction_date))"), "YEAR(transaction_date)", "trx_type", "amount_range", "transaction_value", "symbol"))
    ->leftJoin('companies', 'product.companies_id', '=', 'companies.id')
    ->leftJoin('persons', 'persons.id', '=', 'product.persons_id')
    ->where('companies.symbol', '=', $s->symbol)
    ->where('persons.person_type', '=', 'manager')
    ->whereDate('transaction_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays($days))
    ->orderBy('transaction_date', 'desc')
    ->get();
```